# Resolve promises before loading AngularStrap modal controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-strap

Is it possible to use a resolve section in Angular-Strap(http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals) when opening a modal? I am looking for something similar to how ui-router's resolve section works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that as of Angular-Strap 2.3.0(https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/commit/b272203f7704d2f66873d974beb20e4ac9fd4e7f) you can use `resolve` as well as `locals`, `controller`, `controllerAs`, `template`, and `templateUrl`. `resolve` is still undocumented at this point. I created a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanray/pf2Ls800/